# C: char* is not modifiable

Tags: c, arrays, char

I am writing a really basic trim function in my code:

```
void trim(char a[]){
    if (a[0] == 'a')
    {
        a += 4;
    }else{
        a += 5;
    }
}

int main(){
    char a[] = "add abc";
    char* b = "find abc";
    trim(a);
    trim(b);
    printf("a=%s, b=%s\n", a,b);
}
```

For the trim function, it is supposed to return just "abc" for both a and b. And I checked in gdb, trim(a) worked perfectly inside the trim function. At end of the trim function, a is pointing to "abc". However, when it get returned back to the main function, a became "add abc" again.

Need some help from the community. Really appreciate!!!

Comment: parameters are passed by value, so `a+=4` only affects the local copy and not the value in `main`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is passed by value to `trim`, so it's value is lost after the function returns. Pass it by reference (pointer to array or pointer to pointer) to retain the value in the calling program.

Comment: Pointer to array and pointer to pointer are different things.

Comment: I got what you mean. That is helpful! However, after understanding the reason why this is wrong, I am not sure how could I correct by passing a reference to the trim function. The way I got right is by changing the return type of trim to char* and return a in trim.

Comment: @DavidBowling could you please explaint, where the differences are?

Comment: @Tom.D this is of course a possibility, but that's not what I suggested. I suggest to pass the argument `char **a` (or `char * a[]`) and modify it by `*a += 4`

Comment: @Tom.D according to [this link](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) that the answer to your linked post refers to, arrays and pointers are the same when declared as function parameters. So my statement was right. Of course an array declaration is different from a pointer declaration, since for the array memory is reserved besides the address, but in a declaration as a parameter, no memory is reserved, so pointers and (simple) arrays are completely the same here.

Comment: By way of illustration, note the a function declared with `void func(char (*arr)[8])` takes a pointer to an array of 8 `char`s as an argument. This function will not accept `char **c` as an argument.

Comment: @DavidBowling Wow, thank you! I only now realized the difference! Nevertheless I think the (now edited) post is correct, do you agree?

Comment: @DavidBowling yep, I agree =). If the OP asks for this, I'll write it down. But not today, already way too late in the night now =)

Answer (score 1):

```
char* trim(char* a){
    if (a[0] == 'a')
    {
        a += 4;
    }else{
        a += 5;
    }
    return a;
}

int main(){  
    char a[] = "add abc";
    char* b = "find abc";
    char* c = trim(a);
    char* d = trim(b);
    printf("a=%s, b=%s\n", c,d);
}
```

This will work after I change the return type of trim and catch the retuen value in main function using two new pointer.